# Rephrase the "please don't add thank you" comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I'm interested in this comment that is automatically generated when an Answer is flagged as a "thanks!"

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient
>   reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you
>   found helpful.

It feels slightly aggressive and brusque, and if it's the first comment that a new user receives, could be a potential turnoff.

- Can it be rephrased to be slightly more welcoming, e.g. below? (Not sure if it's a pre-programmed uneditable aspect of the StackExchange site.)
- Am I just being overly sensitive? ;)

> We're glad that this Question helped you, but please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient
>   reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you
>   found helpful.

Comment: I would guess that this is a SE-wide comment not malleable to individual sites; also, as it is SE policy, sort of no-nonsense, non-chatty, it may be that TPTB want it like that throughout. I understand your concern, though. People accustomed to forums can find SE an intimidating place. I think we can make it an inviting site by keeping with [The NEW new “Be Nice” Policy (“Code of Conduct”)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback).

Comment: It isn't terrible -- it does at least say "please" ;)